# What can I use the /testfor command In Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I found the `/testfor` command today in Minecraft, but when I use it in a command block it says

```
Usage: /testfor <player>
```

and when I do that it then says

```
/testfor must be used by command blocks with an analog output.
```

What does that mean and how can I use the command?

Comment: /testfor no longer exists in 1.13

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Minecraft Wiki Commands page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Testfor#Command-Block-only_commands), the syntax of the `/testfor` command is either of:

```
/testfor <playername>
/testfor <selector>
```

So, e.g., a command block that fires the command `/testfor notch`, with a [redstone comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Comparator) attached to it, would output a signal from the comparator, assuming that Notch is playing on that server.

Using the [Command Block selectors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Arguments) syntax lets you do things like `/testfor @a[r=3]`, which will cause the comparator to emit a signal strength equal to the number of players within three meters. Or `/testfor @a[m=2]`, which would cause the comparator to emit a signal strength equal to the number of [Creative Mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creative) players currently on the server.

Answer (score 2):

The `/testfor` command has many uses. For example, you might want to testfor a player with a score of at least 3 on the red team. To do this, you would use the following command:

`/testfor @p[score_objname_min=3,team=red]`

In this command, you testfor the nearest player with a score, on the objective "objname", of 3. This player would have to be on the red team. If you attach this command block to a clock, and put a comparator on the side of it, whenever it finds a player, it will output a redstone signal.

Click [HERE](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Arguments) for a complete list of selectors that you can use within the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use it in a command block so that it can be in a clock or have a redstone input to trigger. You cannot use it from the chat.

You can use it in a lot of ways.

- To get the closest player
- To get the number of players in an area.
- To apply an effect to an area
- To apply certain commands when the testfor returns true.
- Grab the nearest player with a certain scoreboard score.

To Check the result of the command, attach an comparator out of the command block. It will become powered if the /testfor finds a player matching the selector or name.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you did `/testfor @p[r=3]`. It would testfor a single player within 3 blocks.
Suppose you did `/testfor @p[x=3,y=3,z=3]`. It would testfor a player At Coordinates `x=3, y=3 z=3`.